# Manage your calendars permission with Google Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am creating application as like [Sunrise](https://calendar.sunrise.am/), [Calendar by Riddle](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/calendars-by-readdle-sync/id608834326?mt=8), [Tiny Calendar](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiny-calendar-sync-google/id514917848?mt=8), [Calendar 5](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calendars-5-event-task-manager/id697927927?mt=8). I want to sync multiple Google Calendars and using Google Calendar APIs for that. There is one issue when login using OAuth 2.0 with required permission.

Permission window does not asking for **Manage your Calendars** permission.

OAuth 2.0 asking for this permission when we test it from **OAuth 2.0 Playground**

Here is screen shot of Permission Window from **OAuth 2.0 Playground**.

[image]

But same thing not working with iOS Application.

[image]

As you can see that above window asking permission for **Manage your calendars**, but application window not asking for same.

Any help should be appreciated.
Looking for instant help.

If any one have ever implemented multiple Google Calendar Sync then please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think this is possible with OAuth2 scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`, still the same permission will be asked in the `UIWebView`. If you want multiple Calendar Resource of a user, it is possible using `CalendarList: list` which list all the calendar resource then you will just have to list all events per calendar and apply the functions you want for your app. I hope this helps!